# Can't create filesystem folder in a real server?

Tags: laravel, server, config

I just uploaded my application to the real server of my college and I'm having problems with my files folder, on my local server it works well , but in the real server I get this error : Impossible to create the root directory " / home / ... / globalsystem / public / infopath " . and I changed the configuration to the public_html folder on my filesystem.php and I still get the same error.
There are some extra settings that i should do ? here is my filesystem.php config:

```
    'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('infopath'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public_html'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => 'your-key',
        'secret' => 'your-secret',
        'region' => 'your-region',
        'bucket' => 'your-bucket',
    ],

],
```

**EDIT:** 
I changed the app's permissions to 777 too

Comment: Can you run me through how you have deployed this to your server and what you have done?

Comment: You should be giving appropriate permissions to your `public` directory. That's where you are trying to create a directory, right?

Comment: what is your server os? selinux could be the issue when try to write to directory from web application. need to set specific rules on that directory